# Homework: Clearing the hash?

Tags: java

I am using **Java8+** in **NetBeans IDE 8.1**.

*This is part of a homework assignment, but I am looking for an answer more than anything, this time.*

I am restricted to basically just the JDK, and am not allowed to use the following code:

- Regular expressions
- Buffered Reader
- Stream
- Try/Catch
- Lists

Basically my options are restricted to variables, basic string methods (indexOf(), contain(), etc.), for/while loops, if/then or if/else, FileInputStream, Scanner, and other very basic code. Even using my Delimiter to read the file into the array might be questionable.

I have a good bit of code for a simple authentication system. In a text file I have 6 "users" with a username, digest, plain text password, and their account role. I've pulled the text file into a two-dimensional array, and am using that to compare against. User receives a dialog box to enter username, then another to enter a password. A while loop compares the usernames and the passwords, then reports `Good login.` or `Bad login.` The issue is, that it works magnificently for the first user or if incorrect information is entered. For users 2-6, it gets stuck in a "enter username and password" infinite loops. Below is the relevant code. Also, thank you in advance for your assistance.

**File: credentials.txt:** Separators are \t (tab) and \r (carriage return)

```
griffin.keyes   108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f    alphabet soup   zookeeper
rosario.dawson  3e34baa4ee2ff767af8c120a496742b5    animal doctor   admin
bernie.gorilla  a584efafa8f9ea7fe5cf18442f32b07b    secret password veterinarian
donald.monkey   17b1b7d8a706696ed220bc414f729ad3    M0nk3y business zookeeper
jerome.grizzlybear  3adea92111e6307f8f2aae4721e77900    grizzly1234 veterinarian
bruce.grizzlybear   0d107d09f5bbe40cade3de5c71e9e9b7    letmein admin
```

**For the main class:**

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class TestAuthenticationSystem {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, Exception {
        TestSystemLogin sysLogin = new TestSystemLogin();  // Object of SystemLogin
        int loginCounter = 0;                      // Tracks login attempts.
        final int LOGIN_MAX = 3;                   // Max login attempts.

        // Have User attempt to login.
        while (loginCounter <= (LOGIN_MAX - 1)) {
            sysLogin.setCredArray();
            sysLogin.setCredentials();                     // Set credentials
            if (sysLogin.matchUsername(sysLogin.getCredArray(), sysLogin.getUsername()) == true) {
                if (sysLogin.passwordMatch(sysLogin.getCredArray(), sysLogin.getUsername())
                    == true) {
                    System.out.println("Good login.");
                    break;
                }
            else {
                ++loginCounter;
                System.out.println("Bad login.");
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And the second class:**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestSystemLogin {
    private FileInputStream fileByteStream = null; // File input stream
    private Scanner inFS = null;                   // Scanner object
    final private Scanner input;
    private String username = "";                       // Holds username
    private String password = "";                       // Holds password
    private final String [][] credArray = new String[6][4];                 // Array for credentials.txt

    public TestSystemLogin() {
        this.input = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public void setCredentials() {
        System.out.println("Enter Username: ");
        username = input.next().toLowerCase();

        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Password: ");
        password = input.nextLine();
    }

    // Return variable username.
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    // Return variable password.
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setCredArray() throws IOException {
        int i = 0;                                 // Index variable
        int j = 0;                                 // Index variable

        // Import credentials data.
        fileByteStream = new FileInputStream("credentials.txt");
        inFS = new Scanner(fileByteStream);

        // Use carriage return and tab as token separators
        inFS.useDelimiter("[\\r\\t]");

        // Create array of credentials.txt
        for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                credArray[i][j] = inFS.next();
            }
        }
        fileByteStream.close(); //Closes file.
    }    

    public String[][] getCredArray() {
        return credArray;
    }

    // Compare username to recorded username.
    public boolean matchUsername(String[][] credArray, String userUsername)           boolean isTrue = false;
        int i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < credArray.length; ++i) {
            if (credArray[i][0].equals(userUsername)) {
                isTrue = true;
                break;
            }
        }        
        return isTrue; 
    }

public boolean passwordMatch(String[][] credArray, String userUsername) {
        boolean isTrue = false;
        int i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < credArray.length; ++i) {
            if (credArray[i][0].equals(userUsername)) {
                if (credArray[i][2].equals(password)) {
                   isTrue = true;
                   break; 
                }                
            }
        }        
        return isTrue; 
    }

}
```

**What is expected:**
That I could enter ANY of the 6 usernames, and their corresponding password, and receive "Good login."

**What is happening:** 
For Users 2-6, I get stuck in an infinite loop of asking for username and password.

Previous answers suggested instead of using a two-dimensional array, to put each user information into a class. Is this possible without creating additional classes? If so, please provide an example of said class, and the corresponding code to call upon it, for each user.

Comment: Don't use parallel arrays, create a class to hold information for each user. Also you should not store the cleartext password anywhere, that's a security problem, comparing the MD5 hashes is all you need.  You also don't need to "clear the hash" as you create a new MD5 instance each time.  Trace through the code in your IDE debugger to pinpoint where the problem lies.

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, I agree with you wholeheartedly about the security risk of storing the plain-text passwords. In a real-time environment, I would never do that. For this assignment, it was given to us "as-is" and we can't adjust it.

Comment: Oh no! Someone else made a comment that looked like a good explanation of what @JimGarrison was suggesting, then took it away.

Comment: It looks like you need to do some debugging. Break points, assert statements, and debugging with `System.out.println` will be your friend. Stack Overflow questions need to have a [mcve].

Comment: _"Is this possible without creating separate classes?"_ - you already have two classes, is there a homework rule against creating others?  If you're limited to two _files_ you can create an _[inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)_ in the `TestSystemLogin ` class that has name, hash, pass, and role members.

Comment: @StephenP I am not limited to only 2 files, as far as I know. If I create a separate file that has a method for each, name, hash, pass, and role, could you provide an example of code as to how I would use it to systematically check for each user?

Comment: Are your sure about the format of credentials.txt? Because if I create the file in the exact format that you describe I can run your code successfully

Comment: @ThomasKläger Yes, I'm positive. I can see each element of the array has successfully been populated with each string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop will end only if bad login attempts are >= 3, otherwise, this infinite loop will always occur. Also, you need another condition to terminate your loop once you read all entries from your file.

A suggestion, that you read file in ever iteration, fill your array, close file, continue with the whole process, again, read file, fill array and keep doing that which should be changed in a way that you read file only once, populate your two dimensional array and do comparisons.

Comment: If it's a successful login, it should `break;` as well, after displaying the dialog box. It works successfully for my first line of User.

As for your suggestion, could you provide a bit of sample code, as to how I would address multiple Users? Also, to clarify a bit, my `credentials.txt` file has 6 rows of 4 columns, each separated by `\t` (tab) with the fourth column ending in `\r` (carriage return). 

I can see how to create a class to deal with one User, in this case `credArray[0][j]` but how would I then use it to handle the other rows? Thank you for you help.

Comment: I edited my original question to provide clarity, and reduced the code for brevity. If you could check it out, again, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Running your code I had problems with reading the credentials.txt. To verify that your code reads the credentials.txt correctly on your machine output the data that you read by replacing your reading loops with

```
    // Create array of credentials.txt
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS_CRED; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLS_CRED; ++j) {
            String s = inFS.next();
            System.out.print(s+" ");
            credArray[i][j] = s;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

---

In the end, I had to reconfigure the scanner for reading the credentials.txt to accept linefeed characters as separators too:

```
    // Use carriage return and tab as token separators
    inFS.useDelimiter("[\\r\\n\\t]");
```